# Oracle11g: Event Bases Jobs

Tags: oracle11g

I have a temporary table where I store data. I need to poll for the event when data is entered application side (Java EE application). Once data stored in this temp table, I need to use this date to fill a temp table using proc.

I tried using event based jobs. But no use. Please suggest some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm reading this right, you have a table that will store a row with a date in it and a  table that you want to populate based on the data that is entered in the date table.

If the date table is being inserted into using an API, just call your procedure after it. If you cannot do this, you could use a trigger to do this.

eg

```
create table temp_date(
  the_date date
);
create trigger temp_date_ai 
after insert on temp_date
declare
begin
  myproc;
end;
/
```

so every time you insert rows into that `temp_date` table, your procedure would get invoked. if you need the procedure to be asynchronously fired, you could always use `dbms_job` for this:

```
create trigger temp_date_ai 
after insert on temp_date
declare
  v_job number;
begin
  dbms_job.submit(v_job, 'myproc;');
end;
/
```

so when the caller committed the insert into the date table, your job would fire shortly afterwards (as long as your DBA has set up at least 1 `job_queue_process` to handle jobs.

Comment: Hi DazzaL, As you said that one can use trigger to on insert into date table and fill temp table using proc or by defining a job. This solution is perfect when volume of data to be filled in temp table is small... but on insert into date table i need to fill temp table with huge amount of data (approx 10k + rows) involving complex queries (functions). And if i call trigger from Web Application side, it will be slow down like anything.              If we run this report generation query web application side (without temp table) , Production server goes down...   Regards  Mohanish

Comment: When report generation happens, we need to pass dynamic date parameters to query. So i was trying to provide a screen for user to save date in one temp table and on filling temp table, i need to call procedure to fill another temp table to be used for report generation (jasper reports). So need something to poll for filling of date column, so that i can call proc immediately to fill report temp table

Comment: @MohanishTimble so you could have a job submitted as part of the GUI process that loads the table. ie the same as what i did in the trigger example, but just call that dbms_job.submit as part of the client routine that fills the temp table. this would then fire the job asynchronously so wouldnt slow down the response time to the guy who hits "submit".

Comment: Thanks for one solution , will check this out.. by calling job from UI.. and will update you...

Comment: @ DazzzaL : I tried running jobs asynchronously, but not working...check proc below :-   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_asynchronously
( p_some_parameter IN VARCHAR2,p_jobno OUT PLS_INTEGER )
AS
BEGIN

dbms_job.submit( p_jobno,
                   'BEGIN ' ||
                      ' Complex_Procedure( ' || 
                              p_some_parameter || ' ); ' ||
                   'END;' );
  --RETURN p_jobno;
  
END;  --------------------------------------------------------------------I tried running job Java application side,it does not make user wait , but the job does not run either..

Comment: @MohanishTimble  there could be a couple of reasons. firstly did the client commit after calling the procedure (as dbms_job will only fire once its committed). if so, check `DBA_JOBS` for the job entry. if its not running, your dba needs to make sure that `job_queue_processes` (seen in `v$parameter` table) is set to at least 1 for the jobs to work.